# How to throw exceptions for two functions

Tags: c#

I have Two functions. If FunA through exception FunB does not execute. I placed Try catch in FunA code and if exception troughs FunA() display FunA exception. But it is not happening. How to achieve this?

```
try
{
   FUNA();
   FUNB(); 
}
catch (Exception exp)
{ 
   System.Console.WriteLine("Error has occurred during processing:\n" + exp.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Just noticed this bit:

> I placed Try catch in FunA code and if exception troughs FunA() display FunA exception.

Well, you haven't shown the `FunA` code. You've shown the code that *calls* `FunA`. If your `FunA` method *really* has the offending piece of code within a `try` block, and a suitable `catch` block, with no rethrowing, then the exception *shouldn't* propagate (unless it's a `ThreadAbortException`, but that's a bit special).

But otherwise no, `FunB` wouldn't execute. That's how try/catch works - when the exception is thrown, execution flow leaves the `try` block, and doesn't return to where it left off. If you *really* want to execute `FunB` even if `FunA` fails, you need to have the call *after* the `catch` block:

```
try
{
    FunA();
}
catch (IOException e) // Or whatever specific exception you want...
{
    // Logging here... or possibly returning, or rethrowing in some cases
}
FunB();
```

Note how I've caught a *specific* exception here. You should almost never just catch `Exception`, except at the top level of one logical operation (e.g. a web request, or user-initiated action). There are probably going to be relatively few exceptions you can truly *handle* (i.e. situations you can correct) and there are plenty of exceptions which you *can't* handle... so you shouldn't proceed in those cases.

Obviously you can put `FunB` in a try/catch statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret this correctly:

> I placed Try catch in FunA code and if exception troughs FunA()
>   display FunA exception.

Then maybe you need to re-throw the exception in `FunA()` after catching it?

Just add this inside `FunA()` catch block after you print:

```
throw;
```